# Rank of euclidean distance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I prove that the rank of a euclidean distance matrix is $p+2$, where $p$ is the dimensionality of the points from which the matrix was created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dimension $p$, an Euclidean distance matrix has rank less than or equal to $p+2$. 
If the points $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are in general position, then the rank is exactly $p+2$. For a proof see the references [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix), and Theorem $5$ and Theorem $6$ in the article of [Gower](http://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/Gower1.pdf).